# Quickbook invoice create returns 400 bad request (SANDBOX, Quickbook Online, C# MVC, OAuth 2.0)

Tags: c#, quickbooks-online

Well, I am working on creating Quickbook online entries, and for some reason I am getting error (*400 bad request*).

I know something is invalid in my request but I am unable to figure it out. I am using Sandbox account. I have copied default data from API explorer and made request using this data only and finally getting 400 bad request.

My code is working fine for `"Select * from invoice"` query request.

The base URL I am using `sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com`

My Code is as Follow:-

```
var principal = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
Session["realmId"] = XXXXXXX;
var result = new HttpResponseMessage();

if (Session["realmId"] != null)
{
    string realmId = Session["realmId"].ToString();

    string qboBaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QBOBaseUrl"];

    //add qbobase url and query
    string uri = string.Format("{0}/v3/company/{1}/invoice", qboBaseUrl, realmId);

    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Session["AccessToken"]);
        result = await client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(JsonData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return result;
    }
}
else
    return result;
```

Comment: Check the body of the response and see if it provides any details about what is wrong with the request.

Comment: Also some advice. Do not create a new `HttpClient` for each request. It will cause you problems in the futures with sockets if put under load.

Comment: well, yes i will do that with lazyloading concept, this is for testing purpose only.

Comment: i cant find the response field. but i can see the statuscode:400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version : 1.1: Content....

Comment: check the body of the response. ie `var responseContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: Also why are you not using their SDK?

Comment: "{\"warnings\":null,\"intuitObject\":null,\"fault\":{\"error\":[{\"message\":\"message=AuthorizationFailed; errorCode=003100; statusCode=403\",\"detail\":\"The access token does not have sufficient scope\",\"code\":\"3100\",\"element\":null}],\"type\":\"SERVICE\"},\"report\":null,\"queryResponse\":null,\"batchItemResponse\":[],\"attachableResponse\":[],\"syncErrorResponse\":null,\"requestId\":null,\"time\":1524054697091,\"status\":null,\"cdcresponse\":[]}"

Comment: Body tells you the details of the problem **`The access token does not have sufficient scope`**

Comment: yes i got it, thankyou. Where can i Find SDK ?

Comment: Quick google search gave me this link https://developer.intuit.com/docs/00_quickbooks_online/2_build/40_sdks/01_.net

Comment: Thankyou @Nkosi, You solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the body of the response and see if it provides any details about what is wrong with the request.

```
//...

var responseContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

//...
```